# How do I add a kernel module not compiled in my current kernel in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos7

I found kernel modules "**ceph**" and "**rbd**" is configured as `"Y"` or `"M"` in my **centos 7** by looking **/boot/config-xxxx** file.

`Does any guys know what's the best way to add these modules back ?`

Do I need to manually `download` the kernel source code and `configure` these modules to "Y/M"? 
 
Or do I just need to `build` there two kernel modules and `add` them to **/lib64/modules** ?

Comment: Check if kernel module is built the module under the `ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/fs/ceph`, then `modprobe ceph` to get the module loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,

1. I found kernel modules "ceph" and "rbd" is configured as "Y" or "M"

`A kernel module is configured as either "Y" or "M". If you grep for the module under /boot/config it would be marked either of those.`

> **If marked  "Y" then the module is already built into the kernel as a STATIC MODULE. You need not rebuild it once again.**
>
> **If marked  "M" then the module is still built, but as DYNAMIC MODULE. You can find the module by using "$ lsmod" command or can be found in /lib/modules**

`So, if you don't find your module listed under /boot/config*** only then you will have to consider building that module`

Next, if you don't find the modules listed then you will have to download the kernel source corresponding to the version on your PC and then compile only those modules and install them

Answer (score 0):

I find it absolutely asinine that some distros dont have RBD or Ceph built into kernel by default (looking at you, Armbian)